# Null or ' ' values used to create empty space in lightining:recordform stopped working

Tags: lightning-record-form

I am using recordform with 3 columns and trying to put a blank value for middle column. the attribute value of null was working before now it stopped working, and there is no gap between fields. I wanted to know if there is any work around to fix this

```
 <aura:attribute name="test" type="String[]" default="owner, null, name" />

 <lightning:recordForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="Opportunity" fields="{!v.test}" columns="3" mode="readonly" />
```

Comment: is there any reason why you are not using "columns="2" "??

Comment: it was business requirement for layout like that, there was one more recordform above that which has 3 columns, and 3 fields , but this one has only 2 so they want the gap in middle

Comment: Is there a solution to this?  I have a similar requirement.  I am using lightning-record-form to allow both view and edit functionality.  I have two columns of fields for top portion of my form.  One column of fields on bottom portion of my form.  Since the list of fields I provide is populated left to right, I'd like to put an empty space in field to get desired layout.  There does not appear to be a way to do this. Tried null, '' and 'emptySpace'.  None of those are working.